# Assign names of subfolders to corresponding images in an array

Tags: python, image-processing, directory, subdirectory

I have a root directory with many subfolders, each of them contains images. I want to load all of them to an array and assign to each image its subfolder name. Now I know how to load all images to an array of shape e.g. `(10 000, 512, 512, 3)`, which means `10 000` images of the size `512x512` with `3` channels. After assigning the subfolder names I'd like to have a similar array, but I could say about each of the 10 000 images from which subfolder it is.

I'm trying to use `os.walk`. I know how to access all subfolders names and also image names, but I can't figure out how to put them together to one array.

```
import os
from scipy.misc import imread

images = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):  
    for name in dirs:
        print(name)

    for file in files:
        img = imread(os.path.join(root, file), mode='RGB')
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
```

(Also it'd be great if the array didn't contain full strings of subfolder names, but just numbers (of classes/subfolders). I'm not sure if this can be done during this loading process or it'd be done after all images are loaded.)

Comment: What do you mean by assign names of subfolders to images? Do you want a datastructure to store the relationship between images in subfolders? If that's the case a dictionary with the subfolder names as keys and a list of images as values would be best I think.

Comment: That's probably what I'm looking for. I updated the question so it's more clear what I want to achieve. @con--

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import glob
import os
from scipy.misc import imread

images = {}

for file in glob.glob("./**/*.png", recursive=True):
    cwd = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))
    img = imread(os.path.abspath(file), mode='RGB')
    if img is not None:
        if cwd not in images.keys():
            images[cwd] = {}
            images[cwd][file] = img
        else:
            images[cwd][file] = img

for key in images.keys():
    print("{:10s}{}".format(key, list(images[key].keys())))
```

Here's an example directory structure:

```
.
├── f_one
│   └── one.png
├── f_two
│   ├── f_nested
│   │   └── nest.png
│   ├── three.png
│   └── two.png
├── out.txt
└── test.py

3 directories, 6 files
```

and here's the output: (I didn't include the image data since the arrays are quite large)

```
f_two     ['./f_two/three.png', './f_two/two.png']
f_nested  ['./f_two/f_nested/nest.png']
f_one     ['./f_one/one.png']
```

if you just use `print(images)` instead of the last loop you'll get something like this:

```
{'f_two': {'./f_two/three.png': array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
```

Some things to note about this solution:
Using dictionaries means keys have to be unique. If you have any folders with the same name, the last one to be read will be the only one present in the dict. The same goes for duplicate file names within the same directory. If you have non-unique directory or file names, try a different data structure or make sure keys are unique by using absolute paths.